# event.preventDefault() or event.stopPropagation() not working with keyUp event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular10

Directive file: I am trying to do that if my counter goes above two it should stop event or keyUp to reflect but is it not working. Can someone help me on this?

```
import { Component, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export enum KeyCodes {
  LEFT = 37,
  RIGHT = 39,
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  counter: number = 0;
  fragment: string;
  classBorder: string = '';

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // this.fragment = _route.snapshot.fragment;
  }

  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  KeyUpEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode == KeyCodes.LEFT) this.counter--;
    if (event.keyCode == KeyCodes.RIGHT) this.counter++;

    if (this.counter > 2) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed I left some things unanswered, so I updated the Stackblitz to fit your use case.

Comment: If the answer sufficiently addressed your question and/or solved your problem, please consider also accepting it. Thank you, have fun on SO and take care.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create an observable in the OnInit for the event and then pipe it to only take the first 2 values emitted:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
      filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.keyCode === KeyCodes.LEFT),
      take(2),
    ).subscribe(
      (x: KeyboardEvent) => console.log(x)
    )
  }
}
```

The `preventDefault()` only disables default behaviors of the browser, it is commonly used to prevent refreshing on certain events and things like that.

You can also use `takeUntil()` to wait on another observable to fire, for slightly more complex logic like yours.

```js
counter = 0
countSubject = new Subject

get count$() {
  return this.countSubject.asObservable()
}

ngOnInit() {
  fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
    tap((e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (e.keyCode === KeyCodes.LEFT) {
        this.countSubject.next(++this.counter)
      }
      if (e.keyCode === KeyCodes.RIGHT) {
        this.countSubject.next(--this.counter)
      }
    }),
    takeUntil(this.count$.pipe(
      filter((v:number) => v === 2)
    )),
  ).subscribe(
    (x: KeyboardEvent) => console.log(x)
  )
}
```

I made a working example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e1nvxt?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for you.

Answer (score 0):

The stopPropagation() method is used to stop propagating the event from child to parent element, and in this case you are listening to the document's keyup event.
(It's like listening events from the entire body of the document).

Maybe you should change the target from which you listen for the keyup event.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k8cv9h?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts) is a very simple example of stopPropagation() in action with the keyup event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prevent anything, just use the correct logic.

Try this one:

```js
KeyUpEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode == KeyCodes.LEFT) this.counter--;
    if (event.keyCode == KeyCodes.RIGHT) this.counter += this.counter < 2;
  }
```